# How to prevent double submission in magnolia form

Tags: magnolia

I tried to add a handler to Submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit/ Soumettre" onclick='submitform(); this.disabled = true;'>

function submitform()
{
    let myForm = document.getElementById('MyForm');
    myForm.submit();
}
```

but that kills all input field validators (in my case email field validator).

Magnolia should have something for such a common use-case.

Clarification: Model class attached to "Page after submit" perform time-consuming request to service. So the user doesn't see a new page and can click submit button several times.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attaching handler on submit button I put handler on form.onsubmit

```
<div id='shadow' style="display: none; position: absolute; width:100%;height:100%;opacity:0.3;z-index:100;background:#000"></div>
<form id="MyForm" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="blockScreen()"> ... </form>

function blockScreen(){
    let elem = document.getElementById('shadow');
    elem.style.display = 'block';
    elem.addEventListener('click', function(){}, false);
}
```

That shadow blocks the screen and activated only when all validators are completed